# Images in ChartJS CustomTooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have the following code, and wish to add images into each custom tooltip. I simply want to generate the PNG filename from the tooltip name or ID of the tooltip, but cannot seem to get any values that are unique in order to then assign a filename to the image.

```
    var customTooltips = function(tooltip) {


    // Tooltip Element
    var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

    if (!tooltipEl) {
        tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
        tooltipEl.id = 'chartjs-tooltip';
        tooltipEl.innerHTML = '<table></table>';
        this._chart.canvas.parentNode.appendChild(tooltipEl);
    }

    function getBody(bodyItem) {
        return bodyItem.lines;
    }
    // Set Text
    if (tooltip.body) {
        var titleLines = tooltip.title || [];
        var bodyLines = tooltip.body.map(getBody);
        var innerHtml = '<thead>';
        titleLines.forEach(function(title) {
            innerHtml += '<tr><th>' + title + '</th></tr>';
        });
        innerHtml += '</thead><tbody>';
        bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
            var colors = tooltip.labelColors[i];
            var style = 'background:' + colors.backgroundColor;
            style += '; border-color:' + colors.borderColor;
            style += '; border-width: 2px';
            var span = '<span class="chartjs-tooltip-key" style="' + style + '"></span>';
            innerHtml += '<tr><td>' + i + span + body + '</td></tr>';
        });
        innerHtml += '</tbody>';

        var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');
        tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
    }

    var positionY = this._chart.canvas.offsetTop;
    var positionX = this._chart.canvas.offsetLeft;

    // Display, position, and set styles for font
    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
    tooltipEl.style.left = positionX + tooltip.caretX + 'px';
    tooltipEl.style.top = positionY + tooltip.caretY + 'px';
    tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltip._bodyFontFamily;
    tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltip.bodyFontSize + 'px';
    tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltip._bodyFontStyle;
    tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltip.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltip.xPadding + 'px';
};  var customTooltips = function(tooltip) {


    // Tooltip Element
    var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

    if (!tooltipEl) {
        tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
        tooltipEl.id = 'chartjs-tooltip';
        tooltipEl.innerHTML = '<table></table>';
        this._chart.canvas.parentNode.appendChild(tooltipEl);
    }

    function getBody(bodyItem) {
        return bodyItem.lines;
    }
    // Set Text
    if (tooltip.body) {
        var titleLines = tooltip.title || [];
        var bodyLines = tooltip.body.map(getBody);
        var innerHtml = '<thead>';
        titleLines.forEach(function(title) {
            innerHtml += '<tr><th>' + title + '</th></tr>';
        });
        innerHtml += '</thead><tbody>';
        bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
            var colors = tooltip.labelColors[i];
            var style = 'background:' + colors.backgroundColor;
            style += '; border-color:' + colors.borderColor;
            style += '; border-width: 2px';
            var span = '<span class="chartjs-tooltip-key" style="' + style + '"></span>';
            innerHtml += '<tr><td>' + i + span + body + '</td></tr>';
        });
        innerHtml += '</tbody>';

        var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');
        tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
    }

    var positionY = this._chart.canvas.offsetTop;
    var positionX = this._chart.canvas.offsetLeft;

    // Display, position, and set styles for font
    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
    tooltipEl.style.left = positionX + tooltip.caretX + 'px';
    tooltipEl.style.top = positionY + tooltip.caretY + 'px';
    tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltip._bodyFontFamily;
    tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltip.bodyFontSize + 'px';
    tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltip._bodyFontStyle;
    tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltip.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltip.xPadding + 'px';
};
```

The area I need to insert the image into is the forEach loop:

```
bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
```

But adding i++ to the end of it and adding:

```
<img src="image' + i + '.png">
```

in the span element doesn't work because the i variable is always zero (0). SO I just get lots of image0.png.

Any idea on how to get a unique reference in there?

Even if I can get the tooltip name without the value, I can use that. Furthest I have been able to get is inserting the tooltip value and ending up with 'imageName: 0.90.png'. I have tried to do a javascript strip after the ':' on the value, but it just kills the script.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help of a few other posts. Has been a very hard solution to find so figured I'd post it here.

Changing the callbacks to the following allowed me to get the name of the tooltip only:

```
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) { 
                    var indice = tooltipItem.index;                 
                    return  data.labels[indice];
                }
            },
```

Which then allowed me to do as I needed above.